# Consuming all elements of a channel into a slice

Tags: go, channel

How can I construct a slice out of all of elements consumed from a channel (like Python's [`list`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#list) does)? I can use this helper function:

```
func ToSlice(c chan int) []int {
    s := make([]int, 0)
    for i := range c {
        s = append(s, i)
    }
    return s
}
```

but due to the [lack of generics](http://golang.org/doc/faq#generics), I'll have to write that for every type, won't I? Is there a builtin function that implements this? If not, how can I avoid copying and pasting the above code for every single type I'm using?

Comment: There is no builtin for this. It actually seems odd to do this at all: You'll use a channel when you want to pass items one by one from one goroutine to an other and would use a slice if the items form a totality which is processed together.

Comment: @Volker I'm not sure why that would be odd - what if I need to process items that are coming from another goroutine in totality? I have a goroutine that spews out data points (and normally, these go into another goroutine), but I need to process all of the items in two passes, so I'd figured that using a slice would be the better option here.

Comment: It's 2022, and generics are here: https://go.dev/play/p/Bz7xFpiuPp7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there's only a few instances in your code where the conversion is needed, then there's absolutely nothing wrong with copying the 7 lines of code a few times (or even inlining it where it's used,  which reduces it to 4 lines of code and is probably the most readable solution).

If you've really got conversions between lots and lots of types of channels and slices and want something generic, then you can do this with reflection at the cost of ugliness and lack of static typing at the callsite of ChanToSlice.

Here's complete example code for how you can use reflect to solve this problem with a demonstration of it working for an int channel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

// ChanToSlice reads all data from ch (which must be a chan), returning a
// slice of the data. If ch is a 'T chan' then the return value is of type
// []T inside the returned interface.
// A typical call would be sl := ChanToSlice(ch).([]int)
func ChanToSlice(ch interface{}) interface{} {
    chv := reflect.ValueOf(ch)
    slv := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(reflect.TypeOf(ch).Elem()), 0, 0)
    for {
        v, ok := chv.Recv()
        if !ok {
            return slv.Interface()
        }
        slv = reflect.Append(slv, v)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
        close(ch)
    }()
    sl := ChanToSlice(ch).([]int)
    fmt.Println(sl)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could make ToSlice() just work on interface{}'s, but the amount of code you save here will likely cost you in complexity elsewhere.

```
func ToSlice(c chan interface{}) []interface{} {
    s := make([]interface{}, 0)
    for i := range c {
        s = append(s, i)
    }
    return s
}
```

Full example at http://play.golang.org/p/wxx-Yf5ESN

That being said: As @Volker said in the comments from the slice (haha) of code you showed it seems like it'd be saner to either process the results in a streaming fashion or "buffer them up" at the generator and just send the slice down the channel.

Comment: This one will only work with a `chan interface{}` though, so still might not do what he's after.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge True. This is the code that won't work: `c := make(chan int); s := ToSlice(c)`.

Comment: To make it possible Go would need to allow type conversion from `[]int` to `[]interface{}` or `chan int` to `chan interface{}`. It does not allow that kind of conversions. http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

Comment: @Grzegorz & James yes, of course the chan has to be an interface{}, too. The play link has that. As I said I don't recommend doing it this way.

Comment: You could add maximum capacity to slice which should be a slightly bit more efficient. Not much tough.

s := make([]interface{}, 0, len(c))

Comment: @RichardLindhout Does len() work on channels? I thought they could be unbounded

Comment: I'm not sure why I commented such an premature optimisation in 2020. And I think you're right that the suggestion is not good for channels!